# Trouble with foreach and nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm having an issue with `foreach` and nested `arrays` in PHP.  I get the whole `foreach ($var as $newvar)` and such, but I've come across a new requirement that I can't seem to figure out/vizualize.  Here's a simple query:

```
select systems.hostname, capacity_disk.server_id, capacity_disk.disk_mountpoint, capacity_disk.disk_datetime, capacity_disk.disk_device, capacity_disk.disk_capacity, capacity_disk.disk_used, capacity_disk.disk_used_percent from systems left join capacity_disk on systems.id=capacity_disk.server_id where capacity_disk.disk_datetime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(subdate(current_date,3)) and systems.id=44;
```

I get the following result:

```
+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+----------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------------+
| hostname                       | server_id | disk_mountpoint | disk_datetime | disk_device                | disk_capacity | disk_used  | disk_used_percent |
+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+----------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------------+
| server01.example.org           |        44 | /backup         |    1427950800 | /dev/mapper/storage-backup | 1870561476    | 1437491340 | 81%               | 
| server01.example.org           |        44 | /               |    1427950800 | /dev/mapper/storage-root   | 15126920      | 4286048    | 30%               | 
+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+----------------------------+---------------+------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

All this data is expected and is working.

The problem is I can't figure out the PHP logic to run a foreach for each of the hostnames and then iterated through each of the `disk_mountpoint`'s.  Obviously, the first part is easy:

```
$query = $db->Execute("select systems.hostname, capacity_disk.server_id, capacity_disk.disk_mountpoint, capacity_disk.disk_datetime, capacity_disk.disk_device, capacity_disk.disk_capacity, capacity_disk.disk_used, capacity_disk.disk_used_percent from systems left join capacity_disk on systems.id=capacity_disk.server_id where capacity_disk.disk_datetime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(subdate(current_date,3)) and systems.id=44;");

foreach ($query as $server) {

}
```

At this point I could reference the hostname via `$server['hostname']` - which again is fine.  The problem is - for each of the `$server['hostname']` items (1 server in this resultset, but 2 items I'd like to also iterate through), I'd like to iterate over the two `disk_mountpoint`'s and be able to manipulate the data in the table row in the database.  The other catch is that I need to be able to report back all my items and return something in the format of:

```
'`disk_mountpoint`','`disk_capacity`','`disk_used_percent`'
```

So, sample output for the two items would be something along the lines of:

```
'/backup','1870561476','81%'
'/','15126920','30%'
```

I've never done this in PHP and having a hard time figuring out how to put the logic to code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and sample output it's not totally clear why you need to treat this as a nested array, but since a database query always returns a single list, you'd first have to loop through the results to convert them to a nested array as shown below, and then you could loop through that to do what you need.

```
$list_by_server = array(); // initialize an array to organize results by host name
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $list_by_server[$row['hostname']] = $row;
}

foreach ($list_by_server as $server) {
    // any per server setup and actions go here
    foreach ($server as $disk) {
        // process disk details and update database
        // output disk details
    }
}
```

You could also set up a variable to track the current server as shown below and avoid two foreach loops.

```
$current = ''; // initialize tracking car
foreach ($query as $row) {
    if ($current == $row['hostname']) {
        // do something with another row from the current host
    } else  {
        // it's a new host 
        // do something with the row
        $current == $row['hostname']; // updates tracking var 
    }
}
```

Comment: This let's me focus on one `hostname`, but doesn't let me work on multiple rows based on the same hostname.  I'm not sure how to manage multiple items for a single hostname the way I explained above.  Have any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my first code example to show the second loop for the rows within a single host. Is this what you need? If not, perhaps you can include more of your code to show what you are trying to with each group of rows for an individual host.