# How I can merge repeated rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm working on a project that each orgnizations have barriers, each organization can contain 1 or more barriers, and then I need generate an XML file that show each barrier into the organization .

But executing this sql code:

```
SELECT organizations.*, barriers.barrierName AS bname, barriers.type AS btype, geographs.name AS geo, rpd.rpdname AS rpdn, rpd.meaning AS rpdmean FROM organizations 
left join orgbarriers on orgbarriers.idOrg = organizations.id 
left join barriers on orgbarriers.idBarrier = barriers.id 
left join orggeographs on organizations.id = orggeographs.idOrg 
left join geographs on geographs.id = orggeographs.idGeo
left join orgrpds on orgrpds.idOrg = organizations.id
left join rpd on rpd.id = orgrpds.idRPD
```

I get repeated rows like this image:

[image]

Comment: When you do a left join in SQL, you will get multiple results for rows in the main table that have multiple rows in the joined table. If you look closely at the rows in your screen shot, you will see that they actually have different barriers, so they are not duplicates, but rather separate rows in the barriers table for the same organization.

Comment: @theark40 thank you ! how I can I do it? 
I'm confused

Comment: @theark40 Because when I generated an XML file from PHP, Organization 2 is duplicated :(

Comment: Since you want to create a hierarchical output from tabular data you should look at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464314/trouble-with-foreach-and-nested-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword "DISTINCT"

```
SELECT DISTINCT rest of your query
```

Comment: Dear, I've added DISTINCT in query but this way only show 1 row.

I need show all, but ordered inside a xml file.

Comment: Strange: You wanted to get rid of the duplicate row. DISTINCT does this. How did you place it in your query?